# Problems during installing Symfony 2.8 project with composer

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I got problem with running my Symfony 2.8 project on new PC. I have it running on other machine.

After `composer install`

I get this output:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.0
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.1
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.10
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.11
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.12
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.13
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.14
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.15
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.16
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.17
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.18
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.19
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.2
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.20
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.21
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.22
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.23
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.24
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.25
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.26
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.27
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.28
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.29
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.3
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.30
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.31
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.32
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.33
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.34
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.35
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.36
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.37
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.38
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.39
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.4
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.40
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.41
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.42
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.43
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.44
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.45
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.46
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.47
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.48
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.49
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.5
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.6
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.7
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.8
    - don't install symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v2.8.9
    - Installation request for symfony/event-dispatcher v3.2.6 -> satisfiable by symfony/event-dispatcher[v3.2.6].
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony 2.8.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.29, v2.8.3, v2.8.30, v2.8.31, v2.8.32, v2.8.33, v2.8.34, v2.8.35, v2.8.36, v2.8.37, v2.8.38, v2.8.39, v2.8.4, v2.8.40, v2.8.41, v2.8.42, v2.8.43, v2.8.44, v2.8.45, v2.8.46, v2.8.47, v2.8.48, v2.8.49, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9].
```

Here's my composer.json content:

```
 "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "ruudy/metronic-bundle": "@dev",
        "twig/extensions": "^1.3",
        "spraed/pdf-generator-bundle": "v1.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.0",
        "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "dev-master",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "0.12.x",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-amd64": "0.12.x",
        "psliwa/pdf-bundle": "^1.0",
        "respect/validation": "^1.1",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.8",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "^1.6",
        "ci/restclientbundle": "^2.0",
        "winzou/state-machine-bundle": "^0.3.0",
        "symfony/event-dispatcher": "v3.2.6",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "^1.2",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0",
        "liuggio/excelbundle": "^2.1",
        "hipaway-travel/mandrill-bundle": "^1.0",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^2.5",
        "php-amqplib/rabbitmq-bundle": "^1.13",
        "knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle": "^1.10",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.3",
        "jms/serializer": "^1.10",
        "firebase/php-jwt": "^5.0"
    },
```

I think that there is some conflict, but how can I find out which package causes this?

Also I'm curious why this project is running on other environment without any problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After couple of hours I managed to find an answer. Had to change `symfony/event-dispatcher` version to 2. Anyway, I still have no idea why this was working on other environment.